# Getting Rid Of Extra Characters When Printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I am printing out this canvas in python that I am using for a board. When I populate it and print with

```
 for row in canvas:
   print(row)
```

I prints like this :

```
['.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.']
```

I need it to print like this

```
 . . . .
 . . . .
 . . . .
```

Is there something I can do to strip it by chance?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Just use [the string join method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join):

```
canvas=[['.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.']]

for row in canvas:
   print(" ".join(row))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the Python default printing method of a `list`. What you want is to construct a string from your list that looks the way you want.

This should do the trick

```py
for row in canvas:
  print(" ".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the list and convert it to string, then print it:

```
for row in canvas:
   print("".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Python 3, where `print` is function, you might do:

```
canvas = [['.','.'],['.','.']]
for row in canvas:
    print(*row)
```

Output:

```
. .
. .
```

I used so called unpack operator here (`*` before `row`), if you want to know more about that I suggest [this short article](https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/)